# Error:System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

HI I have this for the connection string :

```
<add name="IBSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ISBDB.csdl|res://*/ISBDB.ssdl|res://*/ISBDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sql1;initial catalog=IBS;user id=OKME;password='OKOKOK';MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When the program runs, it is failing on the login, but I am able to login to the server and database using SQL Server Studio. I am trying to read and write to it in the program.

Error:

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'OKME'.

Comment: Try to use `password=OKOKOK` without `"`

Comment: i did but its the same result.

Comment: Does your SQL server have SQL authentication enabled?

Comment: yes the second choice is ticked, Sql server and windows authentication mode is ticked.

Comment: so is that the problem?? should it be windows only? and if they dont want to change, then i need a different login id?